# C++ Reflection Guide/Tutorials

Tags: c++, reflection, c++11

I am finding it difficult to find anyway to implement Reflection in C++. I have only seen examples from AGM::LibReflection and Game Programming Gems 5. Does anyone know of a tutorial or decent code sample for how to do this?

So far I know of Boost/QT's built in system, but I am not looking to use theirs (please do not hamper on this, I find it bloated and I want to roll my own, do not derail the topic).

Comment: If you want to roll your own is it just to learn something new?  If not, then why repeat all the mistakes that others have made when there's a very well established library out there that can solve your problems for you?

Comment: What do you want to achieve using reflection? It is very likely that there is a more appropriate solution for your particular problem, especially since you are doing game dev.

Comment: I want to learning something new and explore it. I am hoping to achieve something that will 1) Expose property (to set and get) and 2) Expose methods so I can eventually call them via script (I mainly am looking for 1).

Comment: Boost is not bloated, except for wrong definitions of bloated. :)

Comment: @jack: What do you mean "Expose property"?  Do you mean, "for each member variable, create a getter and a setter method that can be called from other compile time procedures"?  Or do you mean, "for each class, enumerate the member variables and thier values and print them"?

Comment: @jack: Get/Set are bad design for OO code. It is a caused by the reflection (pun intended) caused by the requirements of reflection needing a way to manipulate the object. C++ doe snot use reflection widely (though it has been done) as there are other techniques that are usually more useful. Reflection is great for building developer tools and serialization frameworks not much else. Referring to boost as bloated as naive at best (I find it contains only the bare(est) essentials only).

Comment: @Ira Baxter: By exposing a property, I mean do each member I choose to expose, I would create either a set or get, then wit the Reflection system I would expose the set, or get, or both as a property.

Comment: @Martin York: I will be using reflection for developer toots and serialization, so it is perfect for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection is rotten way to inspect properties of a program.  You can only "reflect" what the guy designing the compiler wired into the reflection machinery.  That's usually not a lot (what reflection system do you know that will let you peer inside an expression?) and it depends on the language.  And for something like C++, where you are trying to add reflection on *top* of the language essentially as set of APIs, you are going to be extremely limited, or you'll have to code in truly stilted style that lets you in effect declare the reflection data as standard data structures.

You could instead use a [program transformation engine (PTS)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html).  Such an engine manipulates the complete program representation, and can thus technically answer any question which is answerable.  In particular, it can in principle answer all the reflection questions you can imagine, because it acts as a substitute for the compiler, and can see everything the compiler sees.
(In fact, it can see *more* than the compiler sees; the compiler is limited to one compilation unit at a time, and a good PTS can see an arbitrarily big set of compilation units concurrently, and can thus answer questions about the set as a whole).

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) can parse full (and many dialects of) C++, builts ASTs and accurate symbol tables.  Using that, you can implement any static computable reflection, and then use that to produce analysis results or modify the ASTs directly.

DMS is language agnostic; it can do this for a large variety of languages.

Regarding actually using DMS to do "reflection": OP wanted to know how one might implement property getters and setters.   With a PTS like DMS, you parse the source code of the class of interest, and then walk the AST for the code.  For each data declaration inside the class, you literally manufacture a getter for that data, by building up the AST that represents the getter code; for tools like DMS, you can do this by composing patterns of C++ source code that are interpreted to represent the corresponding AST fragments, complete with placeholders you can fill in with other ASTs.   Minor transformations can then modify the original AST to include the generated getters/setters; this produces an AST that contains the original code and the generated getters/setters.  A final step is to regenerat code from the AST, which DMS does by using AST-to-source prettyprinters that are part of the "domain definition" (parser, prettyprinter, name resolver) that make up the language (e.g., C++) front end.

Comment: That is an extremely large and cumbersome library, is there a way you can pin point down what I am looking for?

Comment: @jack: You mean "DMS" is an extremely large and cumbersome library? How is that different than C++0x is a large and cumbersome language? It contains what it needs, to do what it does.  To manipulate arbitrarily tough languages like C++, DMS has to have a certain degree of, uh, sophistication, which you are calling "large".

Comment: I suppose I did word this incorrectly. I was hoping to development my own system, rather then incorporating another library.

Comment: @jack: there's nothing wrong with ambition, but be careful what you decide to bite off, and be clear about when you are playing around and when you're dead serious about getting an answer. Regarding doing reflection in C++, its damn hard because the langauge is extremely complex. The DMS answer was intended for those that might consider that you want a very strong, general reflection capability. If your needs are clear (are they?) and much simpler, *maybe* you can implement something as a library/templates/macros that works but C++ is still a tough sandbox to play in. ...

Comment: @jack: if you are interested in just playing with ideas, then you should pick a conceptually much simpler language like Lisp that has access to its own structures in a way that allows pretty much arbitrary reflection to be implmented. Do your experimenting there; you won't have fight C++ issues. The way you phrased your original question, it appeared you wanted serious reflection so you could apply it to a particular class of C++ applications.

Answer (score 1):

YMMV, but there's GCCXML (www.gccxml.org/) and OpenC++ (http://opencxx.sourceforge.net/) if you're looking for an external tool.  Mark-up libraries abound....

Comment: That gets you access to some information about data declations (and maybe function signatures).   Like other "reflection" schemes, it doesn't give you access to the full language.   If that's OK for you, fine.