# Why don't many compiled languages include compile time Reflection?

Tags: c++, reflection, compilation, language-agnostic, language-design

I'm researching this topic for a possible future data serialization program. I'm very baffled why many popular languages (C++ mainly, but Rust too) don't see compile time reflection as something to be supported.

This frequently comes up in data serialization. Given a class, the ability to loop over their data members, get their method names, retrieve the class name, and push all that to $DATA_FILE_TYPE would be incredible.

I'm asking from the perspective of a scientist. I frequently deal with lots of different hardware. Storing data is cheap, experiments are not. Being able to cleanly save structs and classes, and writing the serializer and deserializer once for a data format, then not worrying about changing classes would be amazing.

[ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/how-generate-dictionary) is a good example of the benefits of compile time reflection. While it uses a meta-compiler program to read the source code on a first pass, ideally it wouldn't have to. It's 2015 and it is frustrating for many people to not be able to write a ROOT like library, for the data format of their choice (HDF5, JSON, TXT, ..).

Is what I am describing possible in any popular compiled language?

Comment: There's a C++ working group for compile-time reflection. But it's years away from making it into the standard.

Comment: Use metaprogramming, if you really want to do that.

Comment: Study Group 7 (SG7) of the C++ standard committee is working on this. The short answer to why it's not already there is that the committee (at least primarily) attempts to standardize existing practice, and there isn't sufficient existing practice in C++ to standardize.

Comment: If Haskell can be considered popular enough for your tastes, [there's a library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html) that produces JSON (de)serializers at compile time.

Comment: See my discussion as to why reflection is a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5086654/120163

Comment: It has been doable in LISP since probably 1958, and in compiled versions of LISP as soon as they appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C, and hence C++, is built on the basic premise "you don't pay for what you don't use".

Reflection takes a great deal of bookkeeping. Things that would be useful for a scientist would be murder for an embedded systems guy trying to fit in only a couple megabytes of RAM.

It's a pain, but reflection can be implemented in a library. I use such a thing in my own code, but only for the small handful of subsystems that need it because I'm running on systems where even exceptions and plain-old RTTI are too expensive.

**As for solutions:** You might look at QT. It's a framework for C++. It provides run-time meta data plus many other things.

**EDIT: Pure compile-time solution:** LEX and YACC / FLEX. Nothing wrong with a vector by any means, but no reason not to let your parser just dump out the serialization function as many of the Java generators do.

Comment: *Run-time* reflection takes a great deal of bookkeeping. Compile-time reflection would only use the information that the compiler already has.

Comment: Yes, I'm specifically only asking about compile time, I am aware of the overhead runtime would incur. Really just a vector of method function pointers and data members is enough for myself.

Comment: Marked as answer, although I think the correct answer is that it is a very difficult topic.

Comment: A lexer is one approach, ROOT basically does just that. I will look at LEX, I think libClang might be promising.

Comment: Its stunning how many people think the LEX and YACC are just the cure for all their program analysis/reflection/metaprogramming needs, just how little of the problem this solves, let alone paying any attention to the sheer complexity of C++.  See my essay http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html